# Is で unnecessary for time references or does direct noun modification have different connotations?

Tags: adjectives, particle-で, nouns

I've seen a lot of sentences where `で` was omitted, like:

> 今朝サンタさんが来なかった

Here we have `今朝` which is a point in time so the sentence should be:

> 今朝**で**サンタさんが来なかった

But it's not. Is there any difference in meaning between these two sentences? Is sentence #2 grammatically wrong? Are there any other particles(?) which can be omitted in the same way?

Also what if it were written this way?

> サンタさんが今朝**で**来なかった

Does it have a new (#3) meaning in contrast to the previous ones?

Comment: See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6100/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/28304/7810, https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32429/7810

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Japanese, the use of particles for time references is generally predicted by whether the time reference is **fixed** or **relative**. For fixed time references, the particle `に` is used to mark the time word. For relative time references, the particle is usually omitted.

Examples of **fixed** time references are named days, times, dates, years, etc.
Examples of **relative** time references are things like 'today', 'yesterday', 'this morning', 'next week', etc.

Moving specifically to your example, you haven't included the meaning you are attempting to translate into Japanese. I am assuming you intended the meaning "Santa didn't come this morning". If so, your example contains a relative time reference ('this morning') and therefore the particle can be omitted.

> 今朝サンタさんが来なかった。(This is grammatically acceptable for the meaning "Santa did not come this morning").

If, on the other hand, you were using a fixed time reference, the sentence would be something like this:

> 12月25日**に**サンタさんが来なかった。  (the particle に is need for a fixed time reference).

*I could add that 今朝で is not actually grammatically incorrect in itself, but it introduces a different meaning than what I assume you intended. 今朝で would be like 'as of this morning' in English, referencing a time period before and up to the stated time. But when using particles to connect events to times ('on' a day or date, 'at' a time, etc), the particle に is used in Japanese.*

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the sentence was from Imabi grammar: https://www.imabi.net/irregularverbs.htm and translation was stated as `Santa didn’t come this morning.` for `今朝サンタさんが来なかった` case. So your guess was totally correct.